# Filter by current users group for linked data source data view

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, xpath, sharepoint-2010

I have a data view of a linked data source that I need to filter a person/group field to current user and current users groups. Currently it works fine if the field is for the current user, but then it excludes groups that the current user is in.

This is currently what the filter looks like:

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Tasks/Rows/Row[contains(@AssignedTo, $UserID) and @Status != 'Completed']"/>
```

Is there a way to have the filter include the current users groups in the web part.

(It is a WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart)

Comment: Can you show us a sample of what the input XML data looks like, including the current user and the groups? And tell us which nodes should be selected.

Comment: I have no idea how to get that. I let Sharepoint Designer do all my heavy lifting and XSLT gives my nightmares. If you could direct me to where i might be able to find it I'll grab what I can. :)

Comment: You might want to migrate your question to the SharePoint StackExchange site.